# Get EJS data on Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to pass data from my node server using ejs to my angular controller so that I can have it available when the controller loads (not interested in Angular or UI router where you can have resolves).

**Node server (using express):**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    names: ["Daniel", "Sarah", "Peter"]
  });
});
```

**Angular controller:**

```
.controller('NamesController', function ($scope) {
  var info = <%= names %>;
});
```

Doing this gives me the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

If this is not possible, I'd love to hear suggestions on how to have pre-loaded data on my page.

Answer (score 8):

I'd pass a stringified version of the array in - then parse it out on the client:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        names: JSON.stringify(["Daniel", "Sarah", "Peter"])
    });
});
```

And remember to quote it (This assumes your controller is in your EJS page)!

```
.controller('NamesController', function ($scope) {
    var info = JSON.parse('<%= names %>');
});
```

If your controller is in your own file, you can use an `ngInit` method:

```
<div ng-init="init('<%= names %>')"></div>
```

And parse:

```
$scope.init = function(stringifiedArray) {
    var info = JSON.parse(stringifiedArray);
}
```

Comment: Nice. I got it to work with ng-init, but I'm curious to see why I can't get it to work the other way.The controller is loaded through ng-controller on the parent div of my ejs file -- which is loaded through an ejs include on another ejs file. Thoughts on why that wouldn't work?

Comment: @DanielFalabella -- So the JavaScript is inside the EJS file, right?

Comment: Are you quoting the variable when you try and write it in? `var data = '<%= var %>';`

Comment: Yeah: `var info = JSON.parse('<%= names %>');` . I still get this error: `Unexpected token <`